# Why am I getting a VBA Macro Run time error 6 overflow?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out why I keep getting this error when I copy and paste a number into a cell. I only get this error when I copy and paste it from my company's system website and not if I copy and paste it from notepad or another excel cell. I've tried declaring it as a string, integer, variant, and long but I've had no luck.

Debug takes takes me to the code referencing the cell I attempted to copy into. Which in this case would be the line containing "OOne = Range("OCell1").Value". Anyone have any ideas?

[Debug Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTOeM.png)

[Sample Text Copying From](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRud9.png)

[Cell After Pasting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA2mO.png)

```
Sub OrderValues()

Set storerange = Range("StoreRef")

Dim OOne As Variant
Dim OTwo As String
Dim OThree As String
Dim OFour As String
Dim OFive As String
Dim OSix As String
Dim OSeven As String
Dim OEight As String
Dim ONine As String

OOne = Range("OCell1").Value
OTwo = Range("OCell2").Value
OThree = Range("OCell3").Value
OFour = Range("OCell4").Value
OFive = Range("OCell5").Value
OSix = Range("OCell5").Value
OSeven = Range("OCell6").Value
OEight = Range("OCell7").Value
ONine = Range("OCell8").Value
OUnder = Range("OCell9").Value

If OSix = "(Custom Reason)" Then
    Range("OPhubRemarks").Value = OFive & " - " & OSeven & " - Submitting a $" & OFour & " refund back to CC ending " & OThree & ". Order: " & OOne & ". Location: " & OTwo & ". Allow up to 10 business days for the refund to reflect onto their CC account."
    Range("EscOrderRemarks").Value = "PI ESC - " & OFive & " - " & OSeven & " - Submitting a $" & OFour & " refund back to CC ending " & OThree & ". Order: " & OOne & ". Location: " & OTwo & ". Allow up to 10 business days for the refund to reflect onto their CC account."
ElseIf OSix = "Iconic order cancelled" Then
    Range("OPhubRemarks").Value = OFive & " - Iconic order cancelled on " & OEight & " - Submitting a $" & OFour & " refund back to CC ending " & OThree & ". Order: " & OOne & ". Location: " & OTwo & ". Allow up to 10 business days for the refund to reflect onto their CC account."
    Range("EscOrderRemarks").Value = "PI ESC - " & OFive & " - Iconic order cancelled on " & OEight & " - Submitting a $" & OFour & " refund back to CC ending " & OThree & ". Order: " & OOne & ". Location: " & OTwo & ". Allow up to 10 business days for the refund to reflect onto their CC account."
ElseIf OSix = "Device was returned to the warehouse" Then
    Range("OPhubRemarks").Value = OFive & " - Refund for device ID " & ONine & " returned to the warehouse on " & OEight & " - Submitting a $" & OFour & " refund back to CC ending " & OThree & ". Order: " & OOne & ". Location: " & OTwo & ". Allow up to 10 business days for the refund to reflect onto their CC account."
    Range("EscOrderRemarks").Value = "PI ESC - " & OFive & " - Refund for device ID " & ONine & " returned to the warehouse on " & OEight & " - Submitting a $" & OFour & " refund back to CC ending " & OThree & ". Order: " & OOne & ". Location: " & OTwo & ". Allow up to 10 business days for the refund to reflect onto their CC account."
Else
    Range("OPhubRemarks").Value = OFive & " - " & OSix & " - Submitting a $" & OFour & " refund back to CC ending " & OThree & ". Order: " & OOne & ". Location: " & OTwo & ". Allow up to 15 business days for the refund to reflect onto their CC account."
    Range("EscOrderRemarks").Value = "PI ESC - " & OFive & " - " & OSix & " - Submitting a $" & OFour & " refund back to CC ending " & OThree & ". Order: " & OOne & ". Location: " & OTwo & ". Allow up to 15 business days for the refund to reflect onto their CC account."
End If

Range("OrderRemarks").Font.Name = "Calibri"
Range("OrderRemarks").Font.Size = 11
Range("OrderRemarks").Font.Color = vbBlack
Range("OrderRemarks").Font.Bold = False
Range("OrderRemarks").Font.Italic = False
Range("OrderRemarks").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
Range("OStore").NumberFormat = "0"

Range("OCell1").NumberFormat = "@"
Range("OCell2").NumberFormat = "@"
Range("OCell3").NumberFormat = "@"
Range("OCell7").NumberFormat = "@"
Range("OCell8").NumberFormat = "@"
Range("OCell9").NumberFormat = "@"
Range("OCell4").NumberFormat = "0.00"

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a named range called "OCell1"? Or is that supposed to be a variable?

Comment: Yes it is a named ranged

Comment: Does it give you the same error if `OOne` is dimmed as a `String`?

Comment: Your unqualified `Range` objects are assuming you are working with the `ActiveSheet` - are you sure the sheet you want is active at the time this runs?

Comment: What's the size of the problem range - a single cell ?   If you widen the column what's the actual value behind the `############` ?

Comment: copy and paste that value from your company's website to notepad++ or MsWord, and turn on the display of special characters (button with `¶` symbol). Carefully inspect every character/digit to make sure that it doesn't have anything other than numeric digits. Text copied from websites often  have invisible formatting characters like non-breaking space etc. causing this.

Comment: Yes even if I declare it as a string I get the same error. Yes the sheet is active at the time that it runs. The actual value that displays in the cell when I click on it is the order number that I copied but the cell will still show only ‘#’ and when I widen it, it’s about 2.5 times the original width. If I copy and paste it into work it pastes only the order number and there are no special characters.